# how to get the components of a webpage

Tags: javascript

How can i get the components of a webpage.I mean when we invoke a webpage there are so many components that gets downloaded like css,js,image files etc. i want to get all these components while accessing the webpage and at the same time few information like (size of the component,download time,server time,client time,network time etc).
Is it possible to get these parameters while navigating the webpage with browser with java script or any other programming language.

Please help,

Thanks and Regards,
Kumar

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  Each "component" (or external resource) is referenced by an HTML element somewhere in the document.  With JavaScript you can reference that element (once you've identified it in some way) and examine its attributes (such as a `src` attribute).  This would give you the URL of the external resource.  It's not clear what you want to *do* with that resource, but you can fetch/examine it.  Some properties of some resources can be directly examined as part of the DOM itself too, such as CSS styling.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use the Developer Tools of your browser?

Comment: thanks for the reply. Actually i am accessing my webpages using an automation tool for functional testing that works on java scripting language.Each and every time once the web page is accessed i want to capture the components and the parameters(client time, server time etc) of all the components so that we can analyze which component is taking more time to download and which parameter is responsible for the same